# Apache Nifi getFile procressor

Tags: apache-nifi

The file is copied from Source directory to Target directory using getfile and putFile Processor but the file in source is not deleted and If i do it manually it get deleted from both the directories
I am new in Apache nifi 
I am following some video in which files get deleted from sourced directory as soon as get transfer.

Answer (score 4):

Right click `GetFile` processor and click `configure`. Make sure that `Keep Source File` property is set to `false`